# JS microtime vs php microtime

Tags: php, jquery, json, gantt-chart, microtime

i'm using a plugin for a ganttchart. i feed the plugin with json:
Plugin: [GitHub - JQuery Gantt](https://github.com/mbielanczuk/jQuery.Gantt)

```
{ "name": "Zbigniew Kowalski",
   "desc": "Administrator",
   "values": [
       {"from": "/Date(1310508000000)/", "to": "/Date(1311026400000)/", "desc": "<b>Type</b>: Task<br/><b>name</b>: Task 5<br/><b>Description</b>: Task desc."}
     ]
},
```

So if i try to generate such a block uhm i get some decent problems with the microtime.

microtime in php gives me: 0.77424900 1315815507
and time: 1315815507

but i need something like 1310508000000.

it can't be the key just to add some 0's ?

Comment: have you tried `round()` in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yu should use `microtime(true)` to geat a float-value and then multiply it by 1000 to get microseconds:

```
$time = microtime(true)*1000;
```

take a look at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) for more information.

Comment: mh ok, i tried it but the event is now 1 day too short. 
silly thing

Comment: lol i added just 86 400 000 and i think it's dirty but it works ;) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to construct a JavaScript date object from a PHP timestamp:

```
new Date('<?php echo date('r'); ?>');
```

Comment: this still isn't the solution, microtime(true) give seconds, not microseconds. you'll still have to multiply.

Answer (score 0):

in you JS you could do:

```
var timer = 1315815507;
var float = Math.round(parseInt(timer)/1000000)*1000000;
```

this will give you: 1316000000

live example at: http://jsfiddle.net/DBjS8/1/